# numbers pyramid in java

Tags: java, numbers

I am a beginner in Java programing and I want to print a pyramid like the one in the image:

[image]

I already have the pyramid (without numbers)
(x is the numbers of lines the users wants)
Any help is good!

```
for (int i=1; i<(2*x+1); i += 2)
{
    for (int k=0; k < ((x-1) - i / 2); k++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: come on ;) your code looks good. The pyramid is almost finished... try to use some conditional expressions (if/else) around this line: `System.out.print(x);` You have the variables `i` and `j` ... maybe you have to count another one (based on `x`). I am sure you are able to solve this!  

Comment: I'll give you a hint: You can do it with one `if-else` in the `for loop` that uses `j`, and one more variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!! Now I understand that I was very close for the answer! And haifzhan your answer is the best!! If any of you know about more pages where I can practice Java programming, I would be happy to visit them, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without break your existing logic, even though it is hard to read, the code can be(see the comments below):

```
        for (int i=1; i<(2*x+1); i += 2)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < ((x-1) - i / 2); k++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if((j==0)||(j==i-1)){
                    // if it is smallest j or biggest j, print 0
                    System.out.print(0);
                }else if(i == 2*x+1 - 2){
                    // if it is biggest i, print 0
                    System.out.print(0);
                }
                else{
                    // the rest conditions, print row number
                    System.out.print((i-1)/2);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

All I did is replace `System.out.print(x);` with

```
                    if((j==0)||(j==i-1)){
                        // if it is smallest j or biggest j, print 0
                        System.out.print(0);
                    }else if(i == 2*x+1 - 2){
                        // if it is biggest i, print 0
                        System.out.print(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        // the rest conditions, print row number
                        System.out.print((i-1)/2);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit simpler to write and read if you make a separate method to print each line and cell and then use an `if` statement to determine what to print. The `cell` method encapsulates all the logic on what to print.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    System.out.println(line(i, size));

private String line(int row, int size) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (int col = 0; col < size * 2 + 1; col++) {
        line.append(cell(row, col, size));
    }
    return line;
}
```

or if you are using Java 8:

```
return IntStream.range(0, size * 2 + 1)
    .map(col -> cell(row, col, size)).collect(Collector.joining())))
```

Finally the method to select the character for each position:

```
private String cell(int row, int col, int size) {
    int offset = size - col;
    if (offset == row)
        return "0";
    else if (offset > row)
        return " ";
    else if (row == size - 1)
        return "0";
    else
        return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for getting the output

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
int space=x-i;
//System.out.println("inside first for");

     for(int j=0;j<(i*2)+1;j++)
     {
         int total_spaces=space;

     if(j==0 || j==(i*2))
     {
      if(j==0)
      {
         while(total_spaces>0)
         {
     System.out.print(" ");
     total_spaces--;
         }
      }

     System.out.print("0");
     if(j==(i*2))
     {
            while(total_spaces>0)
         {
     System.out.print(" ");
     total_spaces--; 
         }
     }
     }


     else
     System.out.print(i);

     }
 System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [answer by @haifzhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414311/5221149), which is an excellent answer since it gives you a solution with minimal change to the original code, it should be pointed out that the formulas can be simplified if the outer loop is also a simple zero-based increment loop.

The three-way `if` statement can be replaced with an inline ternary expression (`?:`), and the code can be enhanced to support pyramids up to a height of 37 by filling the interior with hex digits, as opposed to the current max height of 11.

Compressing the code a bit, you get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x - i - 1; j++)
        System.out.print(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j <= i * 2; j++)
        System.out.print(j == 0     ||    // left edge
                         j == i * 2 ||    // right edge
                         i == x - 1 ? '0' // bottom edge
                         : Character.forDigit(i, 36)); // center hex digit
    System.out.println();
}
```